# Why need to set limit with http request header?

Tags: apache, http, request, webserver

Why need to set limit with http request header?

Everyone knows that the request header is limited( tomcat 8k...),
but I can't find any information why it should be.

Is it related to buffer overflow attacks?

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't _need_ to be limited, but servers pick sensible defaults because if you get a massive header it's more likely that this is a bug than intended behavior.

Comment: yes i know http has no limit on header request.
This limit is intended by the web server and it is allowed to adjust this limit.

I think it looks like this
if(header.length>=8k){
throw("413 Entity Too Large")
}

Answer (score 2):

HTTP doesn't impose limits.

However, if server doesn't impose limits it means that a client could (for example) make a HTTP requests with a header that's many gigabytes in size.

If the server did not set a limit, it would mean that the server has to wait until the client is done sending the header, and in the meanwhile the server has to collect this header in memory, perhaps even exceeding the total memory of the server.

If this were possible, clients could construct HTTP requests that crash servers. To prevent this, servers set limits.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to my curiosity in the apache security book.

Properly configured limits mitigate buffer overflow exploits, preventing Denial of Service (DoS) attacks.